# Custom post type 'Show on screen' didn't apply to number

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to show more custom post types in the admin area, but when I increase the number of posts by adding a number in the screen options and click apply, nothing happens. However, this works with the normal posts.

My code for my custom post:

```
// Register Post Type    
add_action( 'init', 'create_tests_type' );
function create_tests_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Test', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Test', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Test' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Tests' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Tests' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Tests' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Test' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Tests' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Tests found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Tests found in the Trash' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Tests'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Holds our Tests data',
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
        'has_archive'   => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'test', $args );    
}
```

I've searched a lot to solve this but haven't found the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

I used your code and I wasn't able to re-create the error - it seems to be working correctly for me on a fresh 3.5.1 install.

Does this also apply to your other screen options, specifically the checkboxes for columns to display (`comments` or `dates`) ?

If applicable, try deactivating your plugins and seeing if that clears up the issue - this is the only thing I can offer for the moment.